# Could not find method android() for arguments while import android studio project

Tags: android, gradle

when i import android studio project then arise the error could not find android error 22 hoe it is solve

my gradle file is here

```
buildscript
{
  repositories
  {
     jcenter()
  }
  dependencies
  {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:+'
  }
}



allprojects
{
   repositories
  {
    jcenter()
  }
}
task clean(type: Delete)
{
   delete rootProject.buildDir
}
android
{
  compileSdkVersion 25
  buildToolsVersion '24.0.3'
  defaultConfig
  {
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
  }
  productFlavors
  {
  }
}
```

This is my gradle file and it show error like could not find the android

Here is the screen shot of the error
[image]

So please tell me how to solve this error
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
buildscript
{
 repositories
 {
   jcenter()
 }
 dependencies
 {
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
 }
}
```

Do not use + in classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:+'

Answer (score 0):

This is not where you are supposed to add `android {}`  block.

The project structure goes like:

```
DriverApp
--app
----build.gradle
--build.gradle
```

The `android {}` block is supposed to be in the `DriverApp/app/build.gradle` and not `DriverApp/build.gradle`. Move that block and it should fix your issue.

Comment: i deleted android {} block from DriverApp/build.gradle file bt it is automatic generate when i rebuild the project